# How to change permissions on Amazon S3 objects where you are not owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, acl, bucket

We used some period of time Amazon S3 bucket with the public policy (allowed to write and read for all the principals). For this reason, some users published there their own objects with ACL which denies access to all the users except their owner.

Now we have tried to change these objects' permissions but faces an error that we have no permissions to modify such files. I have full administrator access in the AWS console. but can not change those ACLs as well.

I discovered some article in AWS how to become an owner for such objects: here is the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://some-bucket/videos/id/guid/original.mp4  s3://some-bucket/videos/id/guid/original.mp4 --storage-class STANDARD
```

but also throws an error "Access Denied"

Please advise the workaround for how to solve this without requesting AWS support help (cause it is paid now and costs 10% of the company monthly budget what is expensive.)

Comment: Do the credentials you are using allow you to upload other files to this bucket? Also see [Controlling ownership of uploaded objects using S3 Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) to avoid future problems.

Comment: hello. yes, I can upload any objects there and modify bucket ACL but can not modify uploaded earlier objects ACL where the principal is not our AWS account. and for this reason, such an object can not be accessed from our side by application or manually.

Comment: Do you actually want to retain these objects (after taking ownership)? As bucket owner, you can always delete objects (even those you do not own).

Comment: yes, we prefer to keep the objects cause they are the part of your env and we have links for them in our app which can not read them because of their acl. so if we wil not manage to take ownership on such objects we will be forced to delete them all and delete all the links to s3 in our db what is more time consuming then to just take ownership.

Comment: If the bucket is public for both read and write then you should be able to copy the objects over themselves, adding the `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` option to take ownership.

Comment: i have tried to run the command with "--acl bucket-owner-full-control" but got error:"fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden". but currently the bucket is private to avoid the appearing of such an objects with acl where we can not read the object.

Comment: well. even it to switch the bucket security policy to public back i still can not copy the objects with --acl bucket-owner-full-control. getting the error: "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden".